# How to change gulp svg sprites code to work with gulp svg sprite

Tags: svg, sprite, gulp

I wanted to follow this technique  https://www.liquidlight.co.uk/blog/article/creating-svg-sprites-using-gulp-and-sass/ but when I tried to use gulp-svg-sprites I had problem with installation  on Win 7. So I used svg-sprite but then I got

"However I got events.js:72 thro er; // UInhandled error event. ArgumentError: SVGSpriter.compile: "{}" is not a valid mode configuraiton."

I guess I should change these lines below for gulp-svg-sprite. Does anyone can tell me what I should change?

```
  return gulp.src(paths.sprite.src)
    .pipe(svgo())
    .pipe(svgSprites({
        cssFile: paths.sprite.css,
        preview: false,
        layout: 'diagonal',
        padding: 5,
        svg: {
            sprite: paths.sprite.svg
        },
        templates: {
            css: require("fs").readFileSync(paths.templates.src + 'sprite-template.scss', "utf-8")
        }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(basePaths.dest));
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand it might be too late but as the author of [svg-sprite](https://github.com/jkphl/svg-sprite) (and its Grunt / Gulp wrappers) I suppose you got confused by the incompatibility between [gulp-svg-sprites](https://github.com/shakyShane/gulp-svg-sprites) (which was written by Shane Osbourne as a stop-gap until I had ported *svg-sprite* to Gulp myself; mind the "s" at the end) and the final [gulp-svg-sprite](https://github.com/jkphl/gulp-svg-sprite) that is referenced in the liquidlight article. You could probably solve your configuration woes by using the [online configuration kickstarter](http://jkphl.github.io/svg-sprite) that's available in the meantime.